# Three state checkbox plugin with indeterminate state as a question mark

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm developing a website and I've been looking for a plugin which allows me to use three state checkboxes.

Unfortunatly, all the stuff I've found (like here : http://extremefe.github.io/bootstrap-checkbox/) has their "indeterminate" state as a full square or as a dash. I need it to be a question mark `?`

Do anyone has a solution to this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have `?` as an alias to `null`.

In simple words, this plugin uses three keywords to determine the three states of the checkbox, namely:

- Checked: `true`
- Unchecked: `false`
- Intermediate: `null`

All these do not equate to `undefined`, which is technically not `null` in JavaScript and can be used for `boolean` operations. To use this plugin, you just need to include the jQuery Plugin:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-checkbox.js"></script>
```

To use the three state checkbox, you just need to create a checkbox first:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" id="myCheck" />
```

And then make it a three state one:

```
$("#myCheck").checkbox().chbxChecked(null);
```

To get the values from it:

```
switch ($("#checkbox2").chbxChecked()) {
    case true:
        console.log("Checkbox is Checked!");
        break;
    case false:
        console.log("Checkbox is Unhecked!");
        break;
    case null:
        console.log("Checkbox is in the Intermediate!");
        break;
}
```

You can have the full code here:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#myCheck").checkbox().chbxChecked(null);
    switch ($("#checkbox2").chbxChecked()) {
        case true:
            console.log("Checkbox is Checked!");
            break;
        case false:
            console.log("Checkbox is Unhecked!");
            break;
        case null:
            console.log("Checkbox is in the Intermediate!");
            break;
    }
});
```

And to change the icon from `icon-stop` to `icon-question`, please edit the source file, `bootstrap-checkbox.js` on line number `37`:

```
if (checked === null) {
  element.addClass('ambiguous');
  element.html('<i class="icon-stop"></i>');
} else if (checked) {
```

And change it to:

```
if (checked === null) {
  element.addClass('ambiguous');
  element.html('<i class="icon-question"></i>');
} else if (checked) {
```

Hope this helps!

**Fiddle:**

```js
/**
 * bootstrap-checkbox.js
 * (c) 2013~ Jiung Kang
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 */

(function($) {
  "use strict";

  var replaceCheckboxElement = function(checkbox, element) {
    var value = element.val(),
        id = element.attr('id'),
        className = element.attr('class'),
        style = element.attr('style'),
        checked = !!element[0].checked,
        welNew = $('<div></div>');

    element.replaceWith(welNew);

    if (id) { welNew.attr('id', id) }
    if (className) { welNew.attr('class', className) }
    welNew.addClass('bootstrap-checkbox');
    if (style) { welNew.attr('style', style); }
    if (checked) { welNew.addClass('checked'); }

    checkbox.value = value;
    checkbox.checked = checked;
    checkbox.element = welNew;
  };

  var changeCheckView = function(element, checked) {
    element.removeClass('ambiguous');
    element.removeClass('checked');

    if (checked === null) {
      element.addClass('ambiguous');
      element.html('<i class="icon-question-sign"></i>');
    } else if (checked) {
      element.addClass('checked');
      element.html('<i class="icon-ok"></i>');
    } else {
      element.html('');
    }
  };

  var attachEvent = function(checkbox, element) {
    element.on('click', function(e) {
      var checked;
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        checked = false;
      } else if (checkbox.checked === false && checkbox.ambiguous === true){
        checked = null;
      } else {
        checked = true;
      }

      checkbox.checked = checked;
      changeCheckView(checkbox.element, checked);

      checkbox.element.trigger({
        type: 'check',
        value: checkbox.value,
        checked: checked,
        element: checkbox.element
      });
    });
  };

  var Checkbox = function(element, options) {
    replaceCheckboxElement(this, element);
    attachEvent(this, this.element);
    if (options && options.label) {
      attachEvent(this, $(options.label));
    }
  };

  $.fn.extend({
    checkbox : function(options) {
      var aReplaced = $(this.map(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            checkbox = $this.data('checkbox');

        if (!checkbox) {
          checkbox = new Checkbox($this, options);
          checkbox.element.data('checkbox', checkbox);
        }

        return checkbox.element[0];
      }));

      aReplaced.selector = this.selector;
      return aReplaced;
    },

    chbxVal : function(value) {
      var $this = $(this[0]);
      var checkbox = $this.data('checkbox');

      if (!checkbox) {
        return;
      }
      if ($.type(value) === "undefined") {
        return checkbox.value;
      } else {
        checkbox.value = value;
        $this.data('checkbox', checkbox);
      }
    },

    chbxChecked : function(checked) {
      var $this = $(this[0]);
      var checkbox = $this.data('checkbox');

      if (!checkbox) {
        return;
      }
      if ($.type(checked) === "undefined") {
        return checkbox.checked;
      } else {
        checkbox.ambiguous = checked === null;
        changeCheckView($this, checked);

        checkbox.checked = checked;
        $this.data('checkbox', checkbox);
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myCheck").checkbox().chbxChecked(null);
});
```

```css
@import url("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("http://extremefe.github.io/bootstrap-checkbox/css/bootstrap-checkbox.css");
body {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" id="myCheck" /> Click Me!
</label>
```

Check out the above working demo!

Comment: I'm not looking for `?` beeing as an alias to `null`, I just need the indeterminate state to look like a `?` :/. It's alright if the javascript value behind is `null` but my client wants the checkbox's indeterminate state to look like a question mark :/ I cannot do otherwise

Comment: @LeZohan68 Read my answer fully: *And to change the icon from icon-stop to icon-question, please edit the source file, bootstrap-checkbox.js on line number 37:*.

Comment: @LeZohan68 Works? Or you need any help?

Comment: Wait a bit :P Need to include all this !

Comment: @LeZohan68 I have added the gist here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b20a8694bfcc067f865#file-bootstrap-checkbox-praveen-js

Comment: I think I got some problem. When i click on my checkbox (which is a three state one) nothing happens. 
       `<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" id="myCheck" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myCheck").checkbox().chbxChecked(null);
</script>`
The includes are alright i think

Comment: @LeZohan68 Can you make a fiddle and let me know?

Comment: In fact, the classes of the `#myCheck` ARE changing, but the box remains empty

Comment: Yep ! Gonna do this ;)

Comment: I am doing it for you now... `:)`

Comment: @LeZohan68 Ha ha ha!! It works! Check out the fiddle in my answer.

Comment: Nice ! Thanks a lot ! I don't get why it didn't work earlier for me, but never mind ! Thanks for all your help ! :D

Comment: Ha ha... No worries buddy! `:D`

Comment: Stumbled upon this in 2019. Was wondering why couldn't it have been elegant with `css` instead of changing the core file? Something like `.bootstrap-checkbox.ambiguous .icon-stop {
    background-position: -96px -96px;
}` could have done that much easily, don't you think? This css approach leaves the library untouched and easy to update and the flexibility of choosing different icon each time (if needed).

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Er... That's true... I believe I added a PR in the original project to give custom icons. Check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/extremeFE/bootstrap-checkbox/pull/3).